# Change quote to &laquo; &raquo;

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using Drupal 7. A lot of text are using quotes like "text" or «text».
I want that for all older text on the site as well as for new text there will be one type of quotes used: «text».

Can you help me with that? Maybe some text filter or module can do this? Tnx for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module:

[Custom filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/customfilter)

> This module allows you to create content filter using regular
>   expressions. Instead of creating a new module for each filter you
>   need, now you can easily create and organize your own filters. Your
>   filter will appear in the input format configuration page.

**Pattern:** `/([^\"]*)\"([^\"]*)\"([^\"]*)/i`

**PHP Code:** do not tick

**Replacement Pattern:** `$1«$2»$3`

REMEMBER to flush the cache!

ALSO note that this pattern could wreak havoc with tag attributes. So you will have to expand it to exclude quotes surrounding attributes. But that is a question for stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you for advice. But honestly not really understand how it implement with this module.

Comment: for example i use pattern /22/ to replace with - 11. nothing happen. maybe module not work at all?

Comment: Updated answer, please check

Comment: nothing...its seems to be problem with newest version drupal. I have 7.43 - doesn't work. thank you. I try search similar module.

Comment: Weird as I am using 7.43 also. Did you read: https://www.drupal.org/node/210551